# Voice Recognition : Need help setting up Alize on windows 7

Tags: windows, voice-recognition

I want to use alize for voice recognition. I need some guidance in alize setup. I am using windows 7.

Comment: Is this really a programming question or more of a how to in windows> If its the later try posting on Superuser instead

Comment: Mark is right, I had the same feeling that this isn't programming related.  But do add more details about what you are trying to accomplish before posting on SuperUser.  Are you trying to control your computer using voice?  Dictate content into a document?  What problems are you running into?

Comment: I have install HTK on my Path , now I am installing ALIZE 3.0 , but in my cmd cnt find ./configure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alize is a toolkit for speaker recognition , verification and segmentation.

To set up the system once you have compiled alize binaries the easiest way is to take one of the demos avaliable in the Website.

Alize is decomposed into ALIZE library (.dll/.lib) and LIA_RAL which is a library + some tools that will allow you to build the system by command line.

Alize needs to work with signal parametrizations (features) extracted by other libraries like : SPRO and HTK. I will recommend you to compile SPRO because most of the examples use it, however HTK file format is also allowed or even with matlab  you can save your own parametrization in SPRO/HTK format.

once you got you binaries , spro binaries and your demo folder , just copy the requiered files into the bin folder. Now read the readme and follow the script execution , you may prefer work in cygwin or use a window bash port.

the tricky parts with ALIZE/LIA-RAL are the path manipulation. Most of the "File not found"  exceptions com from un-appropiated format in guide files: paths must be relative, without starting slash and the files does not contain extensions. ej: "*emocions/angry/15a04Wa*". You have to remember that the C code includes the slash and appends the extension to the name using the information present in the corresponding config file.

Check the code for details about parameter meaning , its the easiest way.

Comment: ./configure in CMD is not recognize , i have installed htk  now I am installing ALIZE

Comment: are you using windows or linux? if linux: please ensure you have the requiered packages (Autotools and compilers) if you are compiling for windows, use visual studio solution. A nice compromise is to use cygwin. but again if you ./configure command is not working please install the requiered packages, and READ REAME plz